# Create an array of arrays in Swift

Tags: swift

I have two arrays:

```
var latitude = [100,200,300]
var longitude = [55,66,77]
```

I am trying to make this new array:

```
var coordinate = [[100,55],[200,66],[300,77]]
```

but its not working. Here is my code:

```
var latitude = [100,200,300]
var longitude = [55,66,77]



var x = 0
var y = 0
var coordinate = []

for lat in latitude{
    x = lat

    for long in longitude{
        y = long
    }

    coordinate = [x,y]

}

coor
```

Here is what i get:

```
[300,77]
```

only the last two elements.

Comment: In your failing code, how have you created 'coordinate'?

Comment: To be honest, you code is a bit of a mess! I'd recommend spending a few days going through basic tutorials. You will not doubt find the answer for yourself.

Comment: Logic is doing what it's supposed to you. You are constantly overwriting the value of coordinate so it will ALWAYS be the last values in the arrays ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a suggestion. The comments are in the code.

```
var latitude = [100,200,300] // OK, so these are arrays of Ints
var longitude = [55,66,77] // Is that what you want? Doubles or floats might be more appropriate

var x = 0 // Why declare these out here? In the loop is ok
var y = 0 // You are also forcing them to Ints (and vars, not lets, though you're not changing them)

/* This IS a bit of a mess
for lat in latitude{
    x = lat // This should be ok, but no need to declare x outside the loop

    for long in longitude { // This is wrong - you will always get the last longitude
        y = long
    }

    coordinate = [x,y] // where is coordinate declared, and as what?
}
*/

// I'm not sure why you want an array of arrays - an array of tuples,
// or an array of structs seems more correct, as there will only ever be two elements
// in the inner "array". Here's a struct...
struct Coordinate {
    var latitude : Int // As I said above, doubles might be better
    var longitude : Int
}

var coordinates = Coordinate[]()
if latitude.count == longitude.count {
    for i in 0..latitude.count {
        coordinates += Coordinate(latitude:latitude[i], longitude:longitude[i])
    }
    println("Coordinates = \(coordinates)")
} else {
    println("Mismatch in length of ordinate arrays")
}
```

---

To do it with arrays of arrays (which was the actual question), consider this

```
typealias IntArray = Array<Int> // Again, probably should be doubles...
var coordinateArray = IntArray[]()
for i in 0..min(latitude.count, longitude.count) { 
    coordinateArray += [latitude[i], longitude[i]]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
var latitude = [100,200,300]
var longitude = [55,66,77]

var x = 0
var y = 0
var coordinate = Array<Array<Int>>()

var i = 0
for lat in latitude{
    x = lat
    y = longitude[i++]

    coordinate.append(Array(x,y))
}
```

---

```
var latitude = [100,200,300]
var longitude = [55,66,77]

var coordinate = Array<Array<Int>>()

for (lat,lon) in zip(latitude,longitude){
    coordinate.append(Array(arrayLiteral: lat,lon))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to define the type Array is allowed to store, and the type should be Dictionary

Something like this:

```
var latitude: Float[] = [100,200,300]
var longitude: Float[] = [55,66,77]

var coordinate = Array<Dictionary>()
var i: Int = 0;
for lat in latitude {
    let coor: Dictionary<String, Float> = ["x":lat, "y": longitude[i]]
    coordinate.append(coor)
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Although the syntax is correct, the logic is wrong. Y will always be 77.

Comment: "var: Int i = 0;" is wrong - it should be "var i: Int = 0"