# How do I merge and format arrays in Swift? (X and Y coordinate arrays)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, merge, append

I am attempting to merge two arrays in specific formatting in order to create an array of x and y coordinates that will be used to create a graph.  I have separate arrays of X-Values and Y-Values in [Double] format, for example:

```
var xAxis = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var yAxis = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I wish to merge these such that they are presented in the following format:

```
var chartPoints = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)]
```

or more generally:

```
chartPoints = [(x,y)]
```

I have tried a few different options, such as the append and extend methods to no luck as this does not sort the arrays or format them in the method required.

How can I merge the two x and y axis arrays to a singular formatted array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24259696/3223917

Comment: @Waine: I reopened the question because the linked (duplicate) answer doesn't have a solution as simple as the the one I've provided here, using the `zip` function, and instead of manually iterating the arrays

Comment: @Antonio: If the questions were identical then the proper action would be to close this as a duplicate and add another answer to the "original" question. – However this question is how to create an array of tuples and the other question about an array of arrays, so it is actually not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `zip` global function, which, given 2 sequences, returns a sequence of tuples:

```
let pointsSequence = zip(xAxis, yAxis)
```

You can then obtain an array of tuples by using the proper init:

```
let chartPoints = Array(pointsSequence)
```

Each element of the array is a `(x, y)` tuple - but values are unnamed, so you can access their individual values by index:

```
let point = chartPoints[0]
point.0 // This is the 1st element of the tuple
point.1 // This is the 2nd element of the tuple
```

If you prefer the tuple values to be named, you can make the tuple type explicit:

```
let chartPoints: [(x: Int, y: Int)] = Array(pointsSequence)
```

and with that you can access using either the index (as in the example above) or using their explicit names:

```
let point = chartPoints[0]
point.x
point.y
```

Comment: @careng glad it worked - remember to mark the answer as the solution if it really solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```swift
var xAxis = [1,2,3,4]
var yAxis = [2,3,4,5]

var chartPoints: [(x:Int,y:Int)] = Array()

if(xAxis.count == yAxis.count){
    for i in 0...xAxis.count-1 {
        let chartPoint = (x:xAxis[i],y:yAxis[i])
        chartPoints.append(chartPoint)
    }
}
for pt in chartPoints{
    print("\(pt)")
}
```

result:

```
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
```